# Wiremock request matching - Cannot match url with dynamic path variable when used with WireMockRestServiceServer

Tags: regex, spring-boot, junit, testcase, wiremock

**Stub mapping**

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*)"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
            "isIpBlocked": "Y",
            "serviceMessage": {
                "type": "OK",
                "code": "200",
                "description": "IP validated successfully. No result found"
            }
        },
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

**cannot match the URL**

https://mywebsite/validation/session/687d69ae-42a8-4584-a395-8e0c876bacae
(Both absolute path and the relative path is not working)

Also tried replacing urlPathPattern with urlPattern with no success

Tried all the below combination. Nothing worked

```
/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)
/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*)
/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)
/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*)
```

**Note:** Wiremock version 2.18.0, Spring Boot 2.0

Actually, except url (in stub mapping with absolute URL) nothing is working for me.

It works perfectly if I use Wiremock alone. It doesn't work if I use Wiremock in tandem with WireMockRestServiceServer (spring-cloud-contract).

**Working code - with Wiremock alone**

```
@Rule
  public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8080).httpsPort(443));

stubFor(get(urlMatching("/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*)"))        .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value()).withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
              .withBody("{\"isIpBlocked\": \"Y\"}")));
```

**Not working - code with WireMockRestServiceServer**

```
MockRestServiceServer server = WireMockRestServiceServer.with(this.restTemplate)
      .stubs("classpath:/stubs/**/validate-ip-success-mock-response.json").build();
```

Comment: your `urlPathPattern` is absolute URL, did you try relative path?

Comment: also, please give example of what *is* working for you. If nothing is working then we might need more information in order to help you, as the issue might be somewhere else in your configuration.

Comment: You might want to edit your first stub mapping snippet.  Your urlPathPattern regex is missing a closing parenthesis `([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*`

Comment: It is just a copy paste error. I just added the parenthesis. It is more of a WireMockRestServiceServer issue. It has nothing to do with Wiremock.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed on the WireMock Mailinglist [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wiremock-user/blOOiFaEa5Q) the example should be changed to a relative URL as described in the [WireMock Guide on Request Matching](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#regex-matching-on-the-path-only):

```
"urlPathPattern": "/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*)"
```

Comment: I already tried with both absolute and relative URL. It didn't work. Also, updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interim solution. I have written my own pattern matcher for dynamic path variable.

```
MockRestServiceServer server = WireMockRestServiceServer.with(this.restTemplate)
          .stubs("classpath:/stubs/valic-get-user-details-mock-response.json").build();  //no dynamic url

  Resource validateIpResponse = new ClassPathResource("/stubs/validate-ip-success-mock-response.json");
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https://helloworld.com/validation/session/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*)");
  Matcher<String> matcher = MatchesPattern.matchesPattern(pattern);
  server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(matcher))
      .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess(validateIpResponse, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

I have raised this issue with spring cloud contract GitHub page.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/740